# Error using SSL for Java client authentication with remote Docker host and self-signed CA

Tags: java, docker, ssl

**Setup**
My team and I are building a framework for application workflow management. We are using Java OSGi components inside of Apache Servicemix running on RHEL 7 machines. We want the framework to be able to use Docker installed on a remote host. I have a Docker host configured to allow external clients to issue commands over HTTPS as outlined in the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/), which involves a self-signed CA. The correct CA cert (`ca.pem`), client cert (`cert.pem`), and client key (`key.pem`) are all on the client machine to allow our framework to use the [Spotify docker-client](https://github.com/spotify/docker-client/blob/master/docs/user_manual.md) API.

The CA cert has been imported into the JRE truststore (`<JAVA_HOME>/lib/security/cacerts`) on the client machine.

**Issue**
When our framework starts up, we have a class that initializes the Docker client and attempts to get a JSON response of images from the remote Docker host. The request fails with a `SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate` error *after* the server has been authenticated (see stack trace below).

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)[:1.8.0_131]
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)[:1.8.0_131]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)[:1.8.0_131]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)[:1.8.0_131]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(SSLSocketImpl.java:1769)[:1.8.0_131]
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:124)[:1.8.0_131]
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.sendChangeCipherSpec(Handshaker.java:1130)[:1.8.0_131]
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.sendChangeCipherAndFinish(ClientHandshaker.java:1216)[:1.8.0_131]
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:1128)[:1.8.0_131]
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:348)[:1.8.0_131]
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)[:1.8.0_131]
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)[:1.8.0_131]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)[:1.8.0_131]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)[:1.8.0_131]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)[:1.8.0_131]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)[:1.8.0_131]
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)[:1.8.0_131]
...
...
```

Using `curl` from the command line with the required certificates and keys produces the correct JSON response from the Docker host, so I know the certs are all correct and the Docker host can correctly authenticate the client using them. I've tried importing the client cert and key into the keystore for the JVM, but the error still persists.

The Spotify Docker client configures its own `SSLContext` from the client cert, key, and CA on the Docker client machine to use in its HTTPS requests. I'm definitely not an expert, but to me that means I shouldn't have to import the client cert and keys myself.

Is there anything I am missing when configuring the JVM to correctly implement two-way SSL authentication with a remote Docker host?